# how to use ImageMagick's crop to remove "watermark"

Tags: imagemagick

How can I use ImageMagick's command line utils to crop several iamges so that I remove the watermark on the bottom of them?

### Context

I have a personal website for my family where I post our photos. A family member took several photos with the phone. Every photo has the following text on it: date, name of the phone's owner, model of the phone. I want to crop the photos to cut out this information before posting it online.

This information is at the bottom of the photo and occupies the same height in every photo, so I need to write a script like so:

```bsh
watermarkheight=20 # just a an example
for photo in *.jpg; do
  dimensions=$(identify $photo | awk '{ print $3 }') # it will be like 600x400, width X height
  height=${dimensions#*x}
  width=${dimensions%x*}
  newheight=$(( height - watermarketheight ))
  # i need help with line below
  someCommandToCropTheHeight --width $width --height $height --file $photo
done
```

What I need to know is how to use commands like `mogrify` or `convert` to cut out the "watermark" from the photos.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I would batch process with XnConvert, which is a free - but closed source application. It's not ideal, but it's free and effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ImageMagick's [-chop](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#chop) option
combined with a [-gravity](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity) setting to remove 20px from the bottom of each image.

To save the cropped images in a directory `results`, you could run:

```
mkdir -p results
watermarkheight=20
for photo in *.jpg; do
  convert "$photo" -gravity South -chop 0x"$watermarkheight" ./results/"$photo"
done
```

Related:

- [Chop, removing rows, columns and edges](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#chop) (ImageMagick v6 Examples -- Cutting and Bordering)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked